# How to convert logical column to static checkboxes in a datatable in shiny app?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatables, dt

I want to show a data table with a column of logical values in my shiny app. However, this column should not show `TRUE`'s and `FALSE`'s but static checkboxes instead. So clicking the checkbox should not change anything. I want `TRUE`'s to be converted to checked checkboxes and `FALSE`'s to unchecked checkboxes.

I thought what I found on https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html under section 4.4 might be helpful. Unfortunately, I have no experience at all with javascript. I searched for javascript code that would do what I want and pasted it into my R code as it what is done in the example from the link. However, nothing happened.

Here is a small example:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(DT)

set.seed(42)
A <- rep(0, 10)
for (i in seq_len(10)) {
  random_length <- sample(1:10, 1)
  random_letters <- sample(letters, random_length)
  A[i] <- paste0(random_letters, collapse = "")
}
B <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10, replace = TRUE)
dt <- data.table(A, B)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput("tableId")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$tableId <- renderDataTable(
    dt, 
    options = list(columndDefs = list(list(
      targets = 2, 
      render = JS(
        "function(data, type, full, meta) {", 
        "return data ? '<input type='checkbox' disabled checked/>' : <input type='checkbox' disabled/>'", 
        "}")
    ))))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But the example from the link works:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(DT)

set.seed(42)
A <- rep(0, 10)
for (i in seq_len(10)) {
  random_length <- sample(1:10, 1)
  random_letters <- sample(letters, random_length)
  A[i] <- paste0(random_letters, collapse = "")
}
B <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10, replace = TRUE)
dt <- data.table(A, B)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput("tableId")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$tableId <- renderDataTable(
    dt, 
    options = list(columnDefs = list(list(
      targets = 1,
      render = JS(
        "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
        "return type === 'display' && data.length > 6 ?",
        "'<span title=\"' + data + '\">' + data.substr(0, 6) + '...</span>' : data;",
        "}")
    ))))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I don't know how to solve this issue without any experience with javascript at all so I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

- you typed `columndDefs` instead of `columnDefs`;
- you use the same type of quotes in your `render` JavaScript function, you have to write that instead:

  `return data ? '<input type=\"checkbox\" checked/>' : '<input type=\"checkbox\"/>';"`

Also note it is better to apply the custom rendering only when `type` is `'display'`, that is:

```
render = JS(
  "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
  "  if(type === 'display'){",
  "    return data ? '<input type=\"checkbox\" checked/>' : '<input type=\"checkbox\"/>';", 
  "  }",
  "  return data;",
  "}"
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I realize that the javascript code that I found doesn't really do what I want. When I click on a checkbox it changes. But what I would like to have is a checkbox that doesn't change when I click on it. Do you have an idea how to achieve that?

Comment: @FireSalamander Add `disabled`, like in your post.